# Let $C(X)$ be the column space of $X \in M_{n \times p}$. Starting off the proof of $C(X) \cup C(X)^{\perp} = \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $C(X)$ be the column space of $X \in M_{n \times p}$. Prove or
>   disprove the following statement: Every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in
>   either $C(X)$ or $C(X)^{\perp}$ or both.

I interpret this as $C(X) \cup C(X)^{\perp} \overset{?}{=} \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am using the  definition $C(X) = $ span of columns of $X$.

Clearly $C(X) \cup C(X)^{\perp} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is obvious.

Now let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This is the part where I'm stuck. Any suggestions on starting this off?

Comment: Note that the union of two subspaces is a subspace if and only if one of the subspaces is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a simple counter-example:
$$X = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} \in \mathbb R^{2\times 2}; \qquad y = \pmatrix{1\\1}$$
We have $C(X) = \{(x,0) \mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ and $C(X)^\perp = \{(0,x) \mid x\in\mathbb R\}$

Comment: Ugh, that's usually how it works, isn't it? Stuck with a proof... there's probably a counterexample. Thank you!

Comment: Not "usually". Keep in mind for how long fermats last theorem stood unproved ;) In this particular case, things can easily go wrong. Note that the more interesting (and true) result is $$\mathbb R^n = C(X) \oplus C(X)^\perp$$

Answer (score 1):

> If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces of the vector space $V$, then $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace if and only if either $U_1\subseteq U_2$ or $U_2\subseteq U_1$

*Proof.* Suppose $U_2\not\subseteq U_1$ and let $y\in U_2$, $y\notin U_1$. Let $x\in U_1$; if $U_1\cup U_2$ is a subspace, then $x+y\in U_1\cup U_2$. However $x+y\in U_1$ implies $y\in U_1$, which is false. Thus $x+y\in U_2$ and so $x\in U_2$. The reverse implication is obvious.

So, in order that $C(X)\cup C(X)^\perp=\mathbb{R}^n$ we need either $C(X)\subseteq C(X)^\perp$ or $C(X)^\perp\subseteq C(X)$, that is, that  $X$ either has rank $0$ or $n$.